# Python-ldap ldap.initialize rejects a URL that ldapurl considers valid

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I want to open a connection to a ldap directory using ldap url that will be given at run time. For example :

```
ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com
```

It is valid as far as I can tell. Python-ldap url parser `ldapurl.LDAPUrl` accepts it.

```
url = 'ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com'
parsed_url = ldapurl.LDAPUrl(url)
parsed_url.dn
'dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com'
```

But if I use it to initialize a LDAPObject, I get a `ldap.LDAPError` exception

```
ldap.initialize(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 91, in initialize
    return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(ldap._ldap_module_lock,_ldap.initialize,uri)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 63, in _ldap_function_call
  result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.LDAPError: (0, 'Error')
```

I found that if I manually encode the `dn` part of the url, it works :

```
url = 'ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory%2cdc=example%2cdc=com'

#url still valid
parsed_url = ldapurl.LDAPUrl(url)
parsed_url.dn
'dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com'

#and will return a valid connection
ldap.initialize(url)
<ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject instance at 0x1400098>
```

How can I ensure robust url handling in `ldap.initialize` without encoding parts of the url myself ? (which, I'm afraid, won't be that robust anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `LDAPUrl.unparse()` method to get a properly encoded version of the URI, like this :

```
>>> import ldapurl
>>> url = ldapurl.LDAPUrl('ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory,dc=example,dc=com')
>>> url.unparse()
'ldap://192.168.2.151/dc%3Ddirectory%2Cdc%3Dparalint%2Cdc%3Dcom???'
>>> ldap.initialize(url.unparse())
<ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject instance at 0x103d998>
```

And `LDAPUrl.unparse()` will not reencode an already encoded url :

```
>>> url = ldapurl.LDAPUrl('ldap://example.com/dc%3Dusers%2Cdc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom%2F???')
>>> url.unparse()
'ldap://example.com/dc%3Dusers%2Cdc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom%2F???'
```

So you can use it blindly on any ldap uri your program must handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically encode the last part of the URL:

```
from urllib import quote       # works in Python 2.x
from urllib.parse import quote # works in Python 3.x

url = 'ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory,dc=paralint,dc=com'
idx = url.rindex('/') + 1
url[:idx] + quote(url[idx:], '=')
=> 'ldap://192.168.2.151/dc=directory%2Cdc=paralint%2Cdc=com'
```

Comment: Forgot to mention : url are given at runtime. I would like to avoid any parsing or string splitting.

Comment: Tried it already, it gives me the same error. `ldapurl.htmlHREF()` does return a string that `ldap.initialize()` will accept, but wrapped in `<a>` tags. For now, I extract it with a `<(.*)>(.*)<(.*)>$` regex.

Comment: mmm ok. I know you want to avoid splitting the string, but it shouldn't be a big deal, just find the rightmost `'/'` using `rindex` and just encode the text to the right of it

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, +1. But I will did some more before accepting.